# how to make excel to decide from two sub string action?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, if I had assigned some string search using the `InStr` function for a Word file and another `InStr` call for opening some ppt file( using hyperlink).
This happens when the user types in a user form.
so my problem is if user types both the keywords at once, how to make excel decide which file to open.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If InStr(UCase(textbox1.Text), UCase("name of word file")) <> 0 Then
        'Code
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(textbox1.Text), UCase("name of ppt file")) <> 0 Then
        'Code
    Else
        'Code
    End If

End Sub
```

If the user types the names of both files at once, how do I make the form decide to make which file to open?

Comment: Are you asking "what happens if they type in both file names"? or are you asking "How do I open a file?"

Comment: With your current code the first leg of the `If` logic will win and the word file will open while the ppt will not. If you want it to do the opposite, then check for the ppt first. If you want both files to open, then you need two separate if statements.

Comment: means if user wanted to open ppt but at end of the text he also type the name of the word file. what will happen and how to overcome this.

Comment: Don't use a text box, use a combobox or list box and that way you can control the user input, and whether to allow multi-select.

Comment: *what will happen?* Try it for yourself and find out??? How you choose to overcome it is a design question, not a code question. How do you *want* to overcome it, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: thank you very much. i will try some other way

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others has said in the comments:

```
If InStr(sample_string, "a") Then
    Msgbox("A")

ElseIf InStr(sample_string, "b") Then
    Msgbox("B")

Else
    Msgbox("C")

End If
```

In above example:

- If `sample_string = "a"`, you get `Msgbox("A")`
- If `sample_string = "b"`, you get `Msgbox("B")`
- If `sample_string = "a and b"` you get `Msgbox("A")`

In the last case, you get `Msgbox("A")` because the condition `InStr(sample_string, "a")` is checked first. Once it returns True, it runs the corresponding `Msgbox("A")` code and skips to the `End If` statement. This is how IF-statement works.

---

To control which file gets loaded if `sample_string = "a and b"`, you can either:

1. As @David Zemens mentioned, use another type of form control to limit what the users can do. A combo box or radio buttons would be good.
2. @JNEVILL's comment suggests you can place your higher-priority file on the `IF` block, and the lower-priority file on the `ELSEIF` block. This would work.
3. Personally I prefer to control for that specific case explicitly by adding one more condition in my `IF` block. This is for better readability, and also a good exercise to consider all possible combinations:

```
If InStr(sample_string, "a") AND InStr(sample_string, "b") Then
    'Code to return higher-priority file
    'Or reject the user entry
    'Or whatever you like

ElseIf InStr(sample_string, "a") Then
    'Code to open file "a"

ElseIf InStr(sample_string, "b") Then
    'Code to open file "b"

Else
    'Code to handle if neither "a" or "b" was given

End If
```